# C# WFP MVVM Получить доступ из VM к UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть Окошко с `VM`, есть кнопка с командой,(при нажатии на кнопку должен происходить парсинг объекта, передаваемого через `CommandParametr` и Записывать всё в `TreeView`, так что пихать через `ElementName` не вариант), Какие могут быть способы соединить `TreeView`, и `VM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из VM в View вы не передаете. Это грубое нарушение паттерна.

Вам нужно ваш TreeView привязать к какому-либо полю вашей VM(в простейшем случае).

Далее вызвать комманду, распарсить что надо и когда закончите, передать результат в VM полю, к которому привязан ваш TreeView. TreeView по привязке подтянет данные и отобразит.

Напрямую ничего не ходит, посмотрите внимательнее концепцию паттерна MVVM.

Comment: @babyhn если вам помог ответ, пометьте его как ответ(галочка рядом с ответом), чтобы другие пользователи могли понять, что есть ответ и помог ли он вам.